# An acceptable method to detect a trusted spider and not redirect them

Tags: web-crawler

i've implemented a Single Sign On feature which redirects the user to another domain and back again. Naturally, I don't want search engines (the ones we care about at least) to be redirected, so what's an acceptable solution?

Here's one I found in PHP

```
$agent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if (strpos($agent, "bot") ||
    strpos($agent, "slurp") ||
    strpos($agent, "crawl") ||
    strpos($agent, "google") ||
    strpos($agent, "teoma") ||
    strpos($agent, "spider") ||
    strpos($agent, "feed") ||
    strpos($agent, "index")) {
  return null;
}
```

Maybe the best solution would actually be to detect and only redirect **real users** ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to check for the presence of the rendering engine in the user agent string, such as Gecko/ AppleWebKit/ Opera/ Trident/ as most crawlers don't include this string. That way you will redirect browsers only.

Answer (score 0):

I have concluded that this is an acceptable way of identifying most trusted and mainstream spiders/crawlers ONLY.  If the user has any of the above in their User Agent string then they are either a spider, or someone pretending to be one.

There will of course be spiders/crawlers out there who do not include the above in their User Agent string, and this will not detect them. If that s important to you then do not use this method, and instead seek an alternative and regularly updated solution, which probably utilises an IP address lookup